# How to create aliases for file paths?

Tags: 7, path-aliases

In my content type there is a file field; when I upload files, it creates a file path like sites/default/files/uploaded_file.zip.
Is there a way to change this path to something like dl.example.com/uploaded_file.zip? I checked the PathAuto module, but it doesn't seem to have this feature.

Answer (score 1):

you have these steps:

1. create virtual host for dl.example.com domain and point it to something like `sites/default/files/dl/`
2. create some module and implement this hook: `hook_filefield_paths_process_file()`. have a look at [FileField Paths](http://drupal.org/project/filefield_paths) module.

   function filefield_paths_filefield_paths_process_file($new, &$file, $settings, &$node, &$update) { ... }

Answer (score 0):

You can try [File Aliases](https://drupal.org/project/file_aliases)

> The File Aliases module allows you to use token customizable aliases
>   for your uploaded files, giving you the ability to keep your file
>   system organized as per usual while providing clean looking paths
>   (i.e., no more '/sites/default/files/').